# Street & Number formatting using RegEx: Switch order of various number formats (e.g 0-9 OR 0-9a-z OR 0-9-0-9a-z) followed by text

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Would any RegEx wizard help me understanding how to cover different "variances"?

I got various formats of a street name with number, unfortunately all messed up and looking like this now

**Messy State:**

- [0-9] Streetname (Example: 12 Street)
- [0-9[a-z] Streetname (Example: 12b Street)
- [0-9]-[0-9] Streetname (Example: 12-14 Street)
- [0-9]-[0-9][a-z] Streetname (Example: 12-14b Street)

**Desired State:**

- Streetname [0-9] (Example: Street 12)
- Streetname 0-9[a-z] (Example: Street 12b)
- Streetname [0-9]-[0-9] (Example: Street 12-14)
- Streetname [0-9]-[0-9][a-z] (Example: Street 12-14b)

**Background:**
Since google contacts somehow managed to mess up all my contacts addresses by showing the house-number first followed by the street I want to edit them in google sheets.

I´d love to "show-off" how great I did so far, but the truth is: I got no plan on how to cover all the different cases

Comment: I'm no Google-Sheets expert, but just note that `Street` contains a capital letter, hence the matching regex would be `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: thanks, google sheets excpets standard regex and sorry to mention: street could start with either small or big letters too :(

Comment: Try `\b(\d+[a-z]?(?:-\d+[a-z]?)?)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z].+)` and in the replacement switch the capturing group to `$2 $1` See https://regex101.com/r/Uc12At/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's one solution, relying on there being no spaces in the "number".

```
= REGEXREPLACE(C6, ".+ ", "") & " " & REGEXEXTRACT(C6, ".+ ")
```

Explanation:

```
= REGEXREPLACE(C6, ".+ ", " ")
```

simply deletes the actual number part (replacing it with an empty string). We're left with just the street name, so we add a space.

The second half, which is the same regex:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(C6, ".+ ")
```

finds the number again and sticks it onto the end.

Answer (score 2):

For the formats in your example data, you might use:

```
\b(\d+[a-z]?(?:-\d+[a-z]?)?)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z].+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary, prevent the digits being part of a larger word
- `(` Group 1

  - `\d+[a-z]?` Match 1+ digits and optional a-z
  - `(?:-\d+[a-z]?)?` Optionally match hyphen, 1+ digits an optional a-z
- `)` Close group
- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ spaces or tabs
- `(` Group 2

  - `[a-zA-Z].+` Match lower or uppercase a-z followed by any char 1+ times
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uc12At/1)

For example

```
= REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "\b(\d+[a-z]?(?:-\d+[a-z]?)?)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z].+)", "$2 $1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "^\d"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, " (.*)")&" "&REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "\s(.+)", ), A1:A))
```

[image: 0]